# Biber in tool mode: how to use map_foreach and $MAPLOOP?

Tags: biber, foreach

I'm trying to manipulate bibtex files using biber in tool mode: given the source file source.bib:

```
@article{key1,
  group = {A}
}
@article{key2,
  group = {A, B}
}
```

I need to produce:

```
@article{key1,
  group = {A},
  keywords = {RG;Group A}
}
@article{key2,
  group = {A, B},
  keywords = {RG;Group A; Group B}
}
```

I type "biber --tool --configfile=group.conf source.bib" with the configuration file group.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
     <sourcemap>
        <maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
            <map map_overwrite="1">
                <map_step map_field_source="group" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="keywords" map_field_value="RG" map_append="1"/>
            </map>
            <map map_overwrite="1" map_foreach="group">
                <map_step map_field_set="keywords" map_field_value=";Group $MAPLOOP" map_append="1"/>
            </map>
        </maps>
     </sourcemap>
</config>
```

and I'm getting:

```
@ARTICLE{key1,
  GROUP    = {A},
  KEYWORDS = {RG;Group $MAPLOOP},
}

@ARTICLE{key2,
  GROUP    = {A, B},
  KEYWORDS = {RG;Group $MAPLOOP},
}
```

Can someone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.

I can't reproduce your results. I get two differences: 1 - `$MAPLOOP` does get expanded as advertised; 2 - `group` fields go missing, I'm not sure why, but I suppose it's because this field is not part of the datamodel.

I could achieve your desired results with the following settings:

`souce.bib` (with `usera` instead of `group`):

```
@article{key1,
  usera = {A}
}
@article{key2,
  usera = {A, B}
}
```

`group.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
     <sourcemap>
        <maps datatype="bibtex">
            <map map_overwrite="1">
                <map_step map_field_source="usera" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="keywords" map_field_value="RG" map_append="1"/>
            </map>
            <map map_overwrite="1" map_foreach="usera">
                <map_step map_field_set="keywords" map_field_value=";Group $MAPLOOP" map_append="1"/>
            </map>
        </maps>
     </sourcemap>
</config>
```

With `biber --tool --configfile=group.conf source.bib` this results in `source_bibertool.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{key1,
  KEYWORDS = {RG;Group A},
  USERA = {A},
}

@ARTICLE{key2,
  KEYWORDS = {RG;Group A;Group B},
  USERA = {A, B},
}
```

So I'm not really sure what's going wrong. Can you report if this small change helps? If not, the only thing I can think of is an out of date version (but that's just a not very imaginative hunch). Which biber version are you using?

Comment: Many thanks! I was using biber 2.1 on a mac (MacTeX 2015). I also have MacTeX 2016 installed, which has biber 2.5. With the version 2.5 everything works, including with the custom field name "group".

Comment: Well, current version on CTAN is 2.10, and with it, without additional definitions, "group" is dropped (as I said, I don't really know why). So, if you plan to use this for a one time job, I suppose it's fine. Otherwise, it is better consider the field choice with care.

Comment: See discussion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415013/105447 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028/105447 to get an explanation why the `group` field is dropped.