# Automatically remove fields from .bib file containing biblatex entries such as @Thesis

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibtool, bibitem

I need to automatically remove certain fields - e.g. `abstract`, `review`, `group`, and `file` - from .bib files that contain not only bibtex entries but also (newer) biblatex entries such as `@Thesis`. This is the same as asked and answered [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371401/remove-abstracts-from-bib), but for files including biblatex entries.

This is how an example entry for a `@Thesis` in the .bib file might look like:

```
 @Thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
  author      = {Mr Author},
  title       = {The Thesis},
  type        = {Doctoral Dissertation},
  institution = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  year        = {2018},
  abstract    = {This is the abstract.},
  file        = {:author/Author_18_TheThesis.pdf:PDF},
  review      = {This is the review.},
  groups      = {publications},
}
```

[bibtool](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool), which is the accepted answer is the referred question, does not yet seem to support such entries and skips them with a warning:

```
@Thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
_^
*** BibTool ERROR:  (line 123 in ./yourbibliography.bib): Unknown entry type

*** BibTool WARNING: Skipping to next '@'
```

How would you automatically remove such fields from .bib files containing biblatex entries? (I would prefer solutions that run on a Linux machine).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You question will probably receive more attention if you include some sample bibentries for people to try things out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Andrew Swann's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371429/105447) using bibtool originally linked in the OP does work, provided the resource `biblatex` is given (ht to moewe).

So, for a file `remove-fields.rsc`:

```
preserve.keys = On
preserve.key.case = On
resource{biblatex}
delete.field = { abstract }
delete.field = { review }
delete.field = { groups }
delete.field = { file }
```

The command:

```
bibtool -r remove-fields ./references.bib -o new.bib
```

will result in:

```
@Thesis{      Author_18_TheThesis,
  Author    = {Mr Author},
  Title     = {The Thesis},
  Type      = {Doctoral Dissertation},
  Institution   = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  Year      = {2018},
  ispreprintpublic={test}
}
```

Comment: This works just fine. Short note: I also needed to prevent bibtool from changing keys and preventing it from changing their casing, which is possible with `--preserve.key.case=on --preserve.keys=on`.

Comment: @geekoverdose, I added those.

Answer (score 11):

> **Notice**: By default, `biber` silently drops fields which are unknown to the datamodel. So, if you happen to use non-standard fields, see update below.

You can use `biber`'s tool mode with an appropriate sourcemap.

In biber's tool mode it operates on your datasource, so you should run if on command line as, e.g.:

```
biber --tool --configfile=biber-tool.conf <mybibfile>.bib
```

(Of course, `<>` are there just for you to substitute with the adequate file name).

`biber-tool.conf` specifies what you want biber to do with your file. In your case, you want to delete certain fields from your entries, so a sourcemap is the adequate tool for that. The contents of `biber-tool.conf` would than be (with some other options relevant to the control of output appearence):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <output_indent>2</output_indent>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_set="abstract" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="review" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="groups" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="file" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

With this setup, the command above biber will output a new file `<mybibfile>_bibertool.bib` having removed the specified fields.

The result for your entry would be:

```
@thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
  author      = {Author, Mr},
  institution = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  date        = {2018},
  title       = {The Thesis},
  type        = {Doctoral Dissertation},
}
```

**Update**: By default, `biber` silently drops fields which are unknown to the datamodel. So, if you have any of those in your datasource, or if you are unsure and wants to be warned about any ignored fields, use the option `--validate-datamodel`:

```
biber --tool --validate-datamodel <mybibfile>.bib
```

For your entry, that would give you the following warnings:

```
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Author_18_TheThesis' (references.bib): Field 'groups' invalid in data model - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Author_18_TheThesis' (references.bib): Field 'ispreprintpublic' invalid in data model - ignoring
```

Now, if the dropping of these fields is not wanted and you must keep them, you have to extend `biber`'s data model to include them, which can be done in your custom `biber-tool.conf`, by adding of your non-standard field(s) within the `<fields>...</fields>` group. In your case (assuming here these are "literal" type fields):

```xml
<field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">ispreprintpublic</field>
<field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">groups</field>
```

And, within the group `<entryfields><entrytype>thesis</entrytype>...<\entryfields>` add:

```xml
<field>ispreprintpublic</field>
<field>groups</field>
```

The resulting custom `biber-tool.conf` is then:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <output_indent>2</output_indent>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_set="abstract" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="review" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="groups" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="file" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
  <datamodel>
    <fields>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">ispreprintpublic</field>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">groups</field>
    </fields>
    <entryfields>
      <entrytype>thesis</entrytype>
      <field>ispreprintpublic</field>
      <field>groups</field>
    </entryfields>
  </datamodel>
</config>
```

With it, for this input:

```
@Thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
  author      = {Mr Author},
  title       = {The Thesis},
  type        = {Doctoral Dissertation},
  institution = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  year        = {2018},
  abstract    = {This is the abstract.},
  file        = {:author/Author_18_TheThesis.pdf:PDF},
  review      = {This is the review.},
  groups      = {publications},
  ispreprintpublic = {test},
}
```

The output is:

```
@thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
  author           = {Author, Mr},
  institution      = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  date             = {2018},
  ispreprintpublic = {test},
  title            = {The Thesis},
  type             = {Doctoral Dissertation},
}
```

This is not specially straightforward. But, to quote a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415028/prevent-biber-tool-from-removing-non-standard-fields-in-bib-files#comment1037464_415028) from PLK on the matter: "The benefits of having a datamodel in tool mode outweigh this sort of problem."

Comment: Seems to work like a charm. Give me some minutes to check it out on the real .bib files I got here - I'll accept your answer once I see the result.

Comment: Yes, please proceed with care and do some checking, for biber is performing more operations there than simply remove the fields. And even though I know how this works and believe it is safe, I don't have much experience in using this tool in real case scenarios of my own.

Comment: @geekoverdose, I added some of the available options that control the appearance of the output. To be used as required (and if required), of course.

Comment: This approach works well, but it also has a side effect I did not expect: it seems to strip entries of all non-standard-fields, e.g. a `ispreprintpublic` field would be gone afterwards. I can either accept your answer now and ask a new question for this (my preferred way), or if you happen to know how to prevent removal of non-standard-fields you could also just include it in the answer. Thx!

Comment: @geekoverdose, that's indeed unfortunate, and I don't know how to fix it. Perhaps someone else can. You can leave this question open and add the requirement of non-standard fields, or open a new question, as you think it is best. I do think that the silent vanishing of some fields, even if non-standard is a significant problem with this answer anyway.

Comment: AFAIK Biber's tool mode only outputs fields defined in the data model. If you use any fields Biber doesn't know it is silently dropped. I didn't find an explicit passage about this in the documentation I have to admit, so you might want to drop PLK a line about this. You can also request that unknown fields be included in the output `.bib`, but I'm not sure if that is possible. https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: @moewe thx for the pointer. For now I've opened a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415028/prevent-biber-tool-from-removing-non-standard-fields-in-bib-files) at tex to see if anyone knows a way or workaround, but if nothing pops up I might do that.

Comment: @moewe, I see. Thanks for the response! I do think this is worth reporting, if nothing else a clear statement in the documentation would be worth it.

Comment: @geekoverdose, see update. It is not specially convenient, but should be enough, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is the `bib2bib` tool, which provides pretty flexible and reliable ways to filter/extract/expand bibtex entries. This (little known) utility is part of the [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) tool suite. (Note: you have to look for the **PDF** documentation, the HTML documentation does not discuss `bib2bib`.)

For instance, to remove certain fields from a `biblatex.bib` file and save the output to `bibtex.bib`:

```
bib2bib --remove abstract --remove file --remove review -ob bibtex.bib biblatex.bib
```

It is also possible to specify filter and sorting options, rename fields (`--rename <old> <new>`) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it manually using a text editor, like Sublime. 
Activate the Regex function (option+command+R on Mac) and look for:

```
abstract = {.*},
```

and substitute it with nothing.

This removes anything between `abstract = {` and `},`

You can apply this to other fields.

Comment: Well, that depends on the editor used. The OP did not mention his used editor. Could be a solution or not (extra installing an editor for this I would not do) ...

Comment: 2 problems with this:
a) I need to automate the task, hence would need to programmatically use the API of whichever text editor you would suggest. 
b) If I understand correctly then your solution would not work with nested brackets, such as `review={Some \emph{nasty}, nasty text.},` or related special cases. Those are present in my data.