# biblatex: Extract all entries of a given type (say, @book) into a new .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

## Problem statement

I have a large `.bib` file that I would like to split into multiple smaller `.bib` files.

For this I am looking for a parser that allows me to extract, say, all the `@book` entries from the orginal `.bib` file, so I can save those to a new file. The entries themselves should basically remain untouched.

Just in case it helps: I am using `biblatex` & `biber` (under Debian GNU/Linux), which IIRC offer some parsing capabilities that I'd be happy to employ here.

Comment: I would say you should not use LaTeX for that, but some external processing. Which platform (OS) are you on?

Comment: Debian (added this to the original question). I'd be happy to use Perl, sed, or whatnot. However, I remember using biblatex/biber some time ago to extract only the actually cited references from a paper into a new .bib file. I forgot how I did this, but it seemed to work well, so I was wondering whether it might be possible to do this without external tools (not a strict requirement, though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is be possible with Biber's tool mode. Unfortunately, there was a tiny issue with the exact functionality you need in versions before 2.11. The issue has been reported (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/212) and is resolved in Biber 2.11.

Create a `onlybooks.conf` with the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_nottype>book</per_nottype>
        <map_step map_entry_null="1" />
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Then call Biber with

```
biber --tool --configfile=onlybooks.conf <yourfile>.bib
```

and you should be presented with a file called `<yourfile>_bibertool.bib` that only contains the `@book` entries of `<yourfile>.bib`.

The caveat that Biber deletes fields not known in its data model of course also applies here, see [Prevent `biber --tool` from removing non-standard fields in .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028/35864).

---

Alternatively, you can use `bib2bib` of  [`bibtex2html`](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/). You can find out much more in the [PDF documentation](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/doc/manual.pdf).

Use

```
bib2bib -c '$type = "BOOK"' -ob onlybooks.bib <yourfile.bib>
```

to obtain only the `@book` entries of `<yourfile>.bib` in `onlybooks.bib`.

The type must always be in all caps and must be enclosed in quotation marks. On Windows OSes the outer quotation marks should be double and the inner single `-c "$type = 'BOOK'"`, while on Unix it should be the other way round `-c '$type = "BOOK"'`

---

You can also use [`bibtool`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool):

```
bibtool --select{@book} all.bib -o some.bib
```

Writes only the `@book` entries of `all.bib` to `some.bib`

Some bibliography managers like JabRef also offer to filter `.bib` files, maybe that can be used here as well.

Comment: moewe, I think you didn't mean `onlybook.bcf` in the second paragraph.

Comment: @gusbrs Ah yes, indeed. Thank you for spotting that. Edited.

Comment: I'd love to accept this answer, but might have to wait for the `biber` fix to try the first proposed solution. I tried the `bib2bib` and `bibtool` suggestions, but run into parsing errors with both: `bibtool` does not seem to be flexible enough to handle "unusual" types such as `@online` or `@report`. `bib2bib` also runs into parse errors, without providing useful information as to what exactly caused it. I'll try to remember to check in on this question after `biber` updates to v2.11 on my machine.

Comment: @FlorianH. At least `bibtool` can be made to accept all common `biblatex` types: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415044/35864.

Comment: I checked in on the first `biber --tool` solution (now that biber v2.11 is installed on my machine), and it works so beautifully I want to cry! The only flaw is that the output file entirely omits any custom output fields in any of the entries. For example, I sometimes add a custom field `mynote = {This is a note},` to a bibliography entry, and `biber`, not recognizing `mynote` as a valid field, will ignore it in the output. Would there be a way to formally define the field `mynote` somehwere, such that `biber` does not ignore it?

Comment: @FlorianH. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028/35864

Comment: Very nice, I'll accept the answer.