# Prevent `biber --tool` from removing non-standard fields in .bib files

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, tools

*This question was about a side effect encountered in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415013/140348). One way to avoid this side  effect is to not use biber but `bibtool -biblatex` as stated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415044/140348).*

I'm using `biber --tool` to automatically remove fields like `abstract`, `review`, `groups`, and `file` from biblatex entries in .bib files. A side effect of this is that all non-standard-fields¹ seem to be removed as well, which I want to prevent. Here's an minimal example:

This is the entry in the .bib file `mybib.bib`:

```
@Thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
 author           = {Mr Author},
 title            = {The Thesis},
 type             = {Doctoral Dissertation},
 institution      = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
 year             = {2018},
 abstract         = {This is the abstract.},
 file             = {:author/Author_18_TheThesis.pdf:PDF},
 review           = {This is the review.},
 groups           = {publications},
 ispreprintpublic = {true},
}
```

And this is the `clean-bibfiles.conf` configartion file for `biber --tool`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
    <output_indent>2</output_indent>
    <output_align>true</output_align>
    <sourcemap>
        <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
            <map map_overwrite="1">
                <map_step map_field_set="abstract" map_null="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="review" map_null="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="groups" map_null="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="file" map_null="1"/>
            </map>
        </maps>
    </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Running `biber --tool --configfile=clean-bibfiles.conf mybib.bib` will produce a `mybib_bibertool.bib` file that contains this biblatex entry:

```
@thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
  author      = {Author, Mr},
  institution = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  date        = {2018},
  title       = {The Thesis},
  type        = {Doctoral Dissertation},
}
```

The non-standard-field `ispreprintpublic` has been stripped from the entry. To be precise, the `groups` and `review` fields would also be stripped even if they would not be in the sourcemap, as both are also non-standard fields or are "borrowed" from the article type, respectively. How to prevent the automatic stripping of such fields when using `biber --tool`?

---

¹See e.g. "2.1.1 Regular Types" and "4.2.4.1 Generic Fields" in the [biblatex documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment without adding these fields to the data model. All unknown fields are dropped. If you need a different behaviour, start a feature request: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: My solution would be to try BibTool, but of course your other question shows you tried it and that is why you ended up with Biber in the first place. I don't use BibTool, but the manual shows a possibility to define new entry types. And BibTool even has a `biblatex` mode that already knows `@thesis`. Run BibTool with `bibtool -r biblatex <file.bib>`

Comment: I've opened the request: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/211

Comment: Ha found, a bit of the docs that describe this. Its in the changes section at the beginning and not in the section describing the tool mode: "Fields which are not defined in the data model described in the default `biber-tool.conf` are ignored and are neither read nor output. If custom fields are required, they should be defined in the data model by using a custom tool mode config file." This confirms my suspicion that it is indeed not possible without a data model definition.

Comment: Oh, there it was then. I sort of tried adding the field with a datamodel, but then it only accepts the fields that are there stated, and not these plus the default data model. Which would then require that the full data model is specified in `biber-tool.conf`.

Comment: You might give `bib2bib` a try, as described in the linked original question.

Comment: 1) Copy the default XML configuration file (to find it: `biber --tool-config`. 2) define a new field in the `<fields>` element: `<field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">ispreprintpublic</field>`. 3) add it to the `thesis` entryfields: `<field>ispreprintpublic</field>`. 4) use your new configuration file...

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to link this answer here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415013/105447. For the record, even though the question and another answer to it are linked in the OP. @PaulGaborit, I wish I had gotten your advice earlier! :) Thanks!

Comment: Seems legit. I think one of you could make a full answer out of the comment above and the details in [the first answer to the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415013/140348) - it might help others running into the same question.

Comment: I guess a self answer would be fair enough here. It is good that the info is concentrated there. But not to leave this one unattended for, with some short outline and the link, might be a good idea as well.

Comment: @PaulGaborit solution is correct.The benefits of having a datamodel in tool mode outweigh this sort of problem. You should add unknown fields to the datamodel by copying the default tool-mode config file. Also, you can force biber to report on skipping things unknown to the data model by using the `--validate-datamodel` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, `biber` does not handle fields which are not part of the datamodel, so
if your data source has non-standard fields or entrytypes, you have to provide `biber` with a data model which includes them.

But, before proceeding with this task, it is a good idea to know what is actually missing in the default datamodel that you need. You can do that with the `--validate-datamodel` option:

```
biber --tool --validate-datamodel mybib.bib
```

On a .bib file containing that entry of yours, that gives you the following warnings:

```
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Author_18_TheThesis' (mybib.bib): Field 'review' invalid in data model - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Author_18_TheThesis' (mybib.bib): Field 'groups' invalid in data model - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Author_18_TheThesis' (mybib.bib): Field 'ispreprintpublic' invalid in data model - ignoring
```

Which lets you know precisely that you have to include the fields `review`, `groups` and `ispreprintpublic` to the datamodel.

(Of course, adding `review` and `groups` to the datamodel to then drop them in the sourcemap would not be the "usual". I'm just doing it here for the sake of generality and procedure.)

To set your custom `biber-tool.conf` file (you called it `clean-bibfiles.conf`, let's keep it that way, but in general there are other operations which could be achieved through this procedure) you will have to adjust the datamodel to include the line(s) of your non-standard field(s) within the `<fields>...</fields>` group. In your case (assuming here these are "literal" type fields):

```xml
<field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">review</field>
<field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">groups</field>
<field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">ispreprintpublic</field>
```

And, within the group `<entryfields><entrytype>thesis</entrytype>...</entryfields>` add:

```xml
<field>review</field>
<field>groups</field>
<field>ispreprintpublic</field>
```

The resulting `clean-bibfiles.conf` should then be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>title</output_fieldcase>
  <output_indent>2</output_indent>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_set="abstract" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="review" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="groups" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="file" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
  <datamodel>
    <fields>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">review</field>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">groups</field>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">ispreprintpublic</field>
    </fields>
    <entryfields>
      <entrytype>thesis</entrytype>
      <field>review</field>
      <field>groups</field>
      <field>ispreprintpublic</field>
    </entryfields>
  </datamodel>
</config>
```

With this configuration file, the command:

```
biber --tool --validate-datamodel --configfile=clean-bibfiles.conf mybib.bib
```

will output `mybib_bibertool.bib` with the entry as desired:

```
@Thesis{Author_18_TheThesis,
  Author           = {Author, Mr},
  Institution      = {Department of Documents, University of Stackexchange},
  Date             = {2018},
  Ispreprintpublic = {test},
  Title            = {The Thesis},
  Type             = {Doctoral Dissertation},
}
```

To check the default datamodel and configuration, you can find the location for the default `biber-tool.conf` with:

```
biber --tool-config
```

This may not be specially straightforward. But, to quote PLK's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415028/prevent-biber-tool-from-removing-non-standard-fields-in-bib-files#comment1037464_415028) above: "The benefits of having a datamodel in tool mode outweigh this sort of problem."