# Using Bibtool to sort a bib file by types and keys alphabetically

Tags: biblatex, sorting, bibtool

I am trying to sort a bib file alphabetically using Bibtool, but I am looking for sorting the entries by types then by keys. For instance, first all the articles, then the books, etc...
With, all the articles sorted alphabetically by keys, then same with the books.

It looks like it should be a command like:

```
bibtool -s -sort.format={@type $key} -i BiBin.bib -o BiBout.bib
```

Comment: alternative: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibsort

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the example on page 60 of the [BibTool manual](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/bibtool.pdf), the type can be specified with `%s($type)`.

Example:

```
@misc{def,
    note = {misc entry 1}
}
@article{xyz,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {On Things},
}
@misc{abc,
    note = {misc entry 2},
}
@article{uvw,
    author = {John Smith},
    title = {Of Things},
}
```

`bibtool -s --sort.format='{%s($type) %s($key)}' -i bibsort.bib -o bibsorted.bib`

```
@Article{     uvw,
  author    = {John Smith},
  title     = {Of Things}
}
@Article{     xyz,
  author    = {John Doe},
  title     = {On Things}
}
@Misc{        abc,
  note      = {misc entry 2}
}
@Misc{        def,
  note      = {misc entry 1}
}
```

Note that you need single quotes in the terminal command to prevent variable substitution by the terminal.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly on my macOS terminal, however it still does not run with cygwin for some reasons...

Comment: Maybe you can try to store the sort format in a resource file and call that with `bibtool -r resource_file` (p. 18 in the manual).

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Biber you can use the following `sort.conf`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sortingtemplate name="tool">
    <sort order="1">
      <sortitem order="1">entrytype</sortitem>
    </sort>
    <sort order="2">
      <sortitem order="1">entrykey</sortitem>
    </sort>
  </sortingtemplate>
</config>
```

Then call Biber in tool mode

```
biber --tool --configfile=sort.conf <yourbibfile>.bib
```

this will produced a sorted file called `<yourbibfile>_bibertool.bib`

The standard Biber `--tool` mode caveats apply: [Prevent `biber --tool` from removing non-standard fields in .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028/35864). Only fields known in the data model will survive tool mode (so if you use fields that are not recognised by the standard data model, you will have to make them known to Biber in a custom data model, see [gusbrs' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415630/35864)).

Comment: That last sentence is disturbing. I just imagined the bibtool doing all kinds of brutal things to the unfortunate fields who happened to not be on the guest list. Lots of bloodshed.

Comment: That's not a problem - you can also customise the data model with `biber`.

Comment: @PLK: It is a bit of a problem: customising the data model is quite a bit of work.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way around this with `biber` - it's designed to be a semantic rather than syntactic tool as that has a lot of advantages for it's main use case with `biblatex`. As a result, it can't know how to parse fields into its internal semantic model which are not in the data model.