# Sorting publications in bibtex in reverse chronological order to display on webpage

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I was using [this procedure](http://people.irisa.fr/Francois.Schwarzentruber/bibtextohtml/) to display publications on my webpage. After implementing it all, I discovered that when I populated the `.bib` file, the resulting display was sorting everything in random year order. Also, some entries would have the same year but would still have their own categories, meaning instead of seeing all publications from 2011 listed under 2011, one would see some entries under 2011 and then others under another 2011 at a random place. Since I cannot fix that code after trying for some time, I am now looking for anything that would reverse sort entries from my `.bib` files by year, so I could display publications on my webpage.

I have seen other solutions that talk about reverse sorting citations in a LaTeX document but in this case, I am not citing anything so I do not want to create a `.tex` document and then `\cite` all my publications, just so I can see them.

How do I reverse sort my publications in a `.bib` file to be displayed on my webpage?

Comment: You can use `bibtool` or Biber to sort a `.bib` file, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426341/35864. For `bibtool` you'd use `bibtool -S --sort.format='{%4d($year)}' -i bibsort.bib -o bibsorted.bib`

Comment: For Biber you need to add replace the two `<sort order="_">` blocks with one block of the form `<sort order="1" sort_direction="descending"><sortitem order="1">year</sortitem></sort>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an existing `.bib` file descending by year with Biber.

Create a file called `ydsort.conf` with the following contents.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sortingtemplate name="tool">
    <sort order="1" sort_direction="descending">
      <sortitem order="1">year</sortitem>
    </sort>
  </sortingtemplate>
</config>
```

Then call Biber in tool mode

```
biber --tool --configfile=ydsort.conf <yourbibfile>.bib
```

this will produced a sorted file called `<yourbibfile>_bibertool.bib`

The standard Biber `--tool` mode caveats apply: [Prevent `biber --tool` from removing non-standard fields in .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028/35864). Only fields known in the data model will survive tool mode (so if you use fields that are not recognised by the standard data model, you will have to make them known to Biber in a custom data model, see [gusbrs' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415630/35864)).

---

You could also try the [BibTool](https://ctan.org/pkg/BibTool) programme. I don't have it installed on my system, but I'm lead to believe that

```bash
bibtool -S --sort.format='{%4d($year)}' -i <yourbibfile>.bib -o <yourbibfile>_sorted.bib
```

might be what you want.

Depending on your OS you may need to use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) here.