# How to make the first letter in the field names of a bib file produced by BibDesk all be lowercase?

Tags: bibtex, automation, bibdesk

As you see, in the following example all the first letters of the field names such as `Author`, `Booktitle`, and so on, are capital. I want to make all of them be lowercase. The file is produced by *BibDesk*. **Since there are many references in the file, is there a uniform way to do this once?**

```
@incollection{Ctfl1956,
    Author = {A. Tarski},
    Booktitle = {Logic, Semantics, Metamathematics, Papers from 1923 to 1938},
    Pages = {152--278},
    Publisher = {The Clarendon Press, Oxford},
    Title = {The Concept of Truth in Formalized Language},
    Translator = {Woodger, J. H.},
    Type = {J},
    Year = {1956}}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you interact with your `.bib` file using BibDesk you never see these anyway.

Comment: @AlanMunn There is an advantage to use BibDesk to open `.bib` file: it can make the format uniform such as the spaces around `=` are equal, `},}` at the end of entries could be replaced by `}}` uniformly, and so on.

Comment: I see the use for BibDesk, I don't see the use for changing the case of the keys.

Comment: @AlanMunn you can also produce keys of entries uniformly by change the setting of BibDesk.

Comment: @AlanMunn: In my case, I use the package `usebib`, unfortunately, it can only deal with lower case fields :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `biber` in tool mode to do the change you want.

From the command line, navigate to the directory where your `.bib` file is and then use the following command:

```
biber --tool --output-fieldcase=lower --output-indent=4 <your-file.bib>
```

This will produce a file called `your-file_bibertool.bib` with the converted format.

Comment: Could you speak in more details?

Comment: @Kuttens I'm not quite sure what else to say. This is a command line tool which is part of the standard TeX distribution. Replace `<your-file.bib>` with the name of your `.bib` file (without the `<>`).

Comment: It can't work, sir.

Comment: @Kuttens Sorry I forgot to mention that the output filename is different.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: It says `Cannot find '--.bib'`.

Comment: Note though that Biber's `tool` mode will align the entries with the standard `biblatex` data model. That could mean that custom fields are removed without warning. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415028/35864