# Typesetting Biblatex Bibliography with Natbib

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

My `.bib`-file is `biblatex`-formatted but I'm now submitting a paper to a journal that requires `natbib`.

Is there a way to tell `natbib` in my preamble to ad hoc convert the `location` field back to `address`, the `date` field to `year`, and `journaltitle` to `journal`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
    Location = {City},
    Author = {Author, Antonia},
    Publisher = {Publisher Press},
    Title = {The Book of Books},
    Date = {1992}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
My book \citep{mybook} ... 
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not that it matters a lot, but the code is not compilable for two reasons: (1) `\reftitle` is undefined. (2) there is no `\bibliographystyle`, so BibTeX does not know which style to use.

Comment: Thanks, I guess those were defined in the journal's class file – I have never used `natbib` before so it's all new territory for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way (e.g. a preamble option) to have BibTeX styles accept `biblatex` fields they do not support (you would have to edit the style file).

Your best bet is to 'convert' your `.bib` file to the correct format with an external tool. Well-known tools for that task include

- Biber (see e.g. [Converting from biblatex to BibTeX format using biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114787/35864) and [How to switch from biblatex+biber to natbib+bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298443/35864)).
- `bib2bib` of the [`bibtex2html` suite](https://www.lri.fr/%7Efilliatr/bibtex2html/) can rename fields (look for `--rename` in the [documentation](https://www.lri.fr/%7Efilliatr/bibtex2html/doc/manual.pdf) and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415037/35864).
- `bibtool` has ways to rename and remove fields as well (`rename.field`, see [.bib files: edition, language, langid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482884/35864), [Automatically remove fields from .bib file containing biblatex entries such as @Thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415007/35864))
- JabRef (I'm not an avid user, but as far as I know it has a BibTeX and a `biblatex` mode. It may be possible to convert a `.bib` file between the two formats.)

But there are many BibTeX parsing libraries for many programming languages, so you could also look at using your favourite programming language.

Of course if you always just have `date = {<year>},` with that spacing a simple search-and-replace in your editor would also work. (Possibly with some RegExp thrown in to deal with additional spaces.)

Note that the set of supported fields and entry types depends on the bibliography style you are using. Even among `natbib`-compatible styles there is not insignificant variation in what is accepted and what not. (It is true that there is a base set of 'standard' fields and types that is supported by most - if not all - BibTeX styles. This base set is good enough for many uses, but was devised before URLs were a thing and so does not include dedicated fields for online sources.)

Comment: These are great resources.   The issue is that I was hoping to be able to submit my `biblatex`-formatted `.bib`-file to the journal and have something in my preamble so when they typeset it it wouldn't choke.  But it seems that might not be possible  (I'm not sure they would be able or willing to process the bibliography file with the `--tool` option of `biber` if I told them to).  So I'll probably have to change my `.bib` file, which I was hoping to avoid :(

Comment: @jan Depending on the journal workflow they may not want you to submit a `.bib` file at all. Often you have to paste the `.bbl` generated by BibTeX into the `.tex` document instead (see e.g. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/The_journal_says_%22don%27t_use_BibTeX%3B_paste_the_contents_of_the_.bbl_file_into_the_.tex_file%22._How_do_I_do_this_on_Overleaf%3F) And even if the journal accepts `.bib` files it might be better to only send them the bits of your `.bib` file that they need (and not the hundreds of papers you have in your database but did not cite).

Comment: In any case I suggest you keep your `biblatex` `.bib` file as is and work with a (possibly reduced) copy that you can format BibTeX compatible for submission.

Comment: Yeah, I will see what files they actually accept (currently have the PDF under review so haven't had to deal with the typesetters yet).  Submitting the `.bbl` file or pasting it into the file is probably the most error-proof solution anyways.